# How to access parent objects scope of variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I just started learning about module Javascript. I have objects called buoys, and there are multiple types of buoys (These are basically popups).

Live chat is one of those types.

I'm converting all of my code to a more module like structure, and I have ran across something problematic.

The code is below, I will leave comments to the parts that need attention.

Look inside the cacheDom function inside the variable `$liveChat`.

The reason I have this liveChat as a child element (Opposed to just putting all of its methods in the parent class) is because it will have unique methods, that would not apply to everything in the parents class. Keep in mind, I am going to have multiple types of buoys. LiveChat is just the only one I have created so far. And these functions that I am going to put in liveChat are going to be unique to liveChat buoys.

```
/* Buoy */
(function{
    var buoy = {
        init: function () {
            this.liveChat.init();
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        cacheDom: function () {
            this.liveChat.cacheDom();

            this.$document = $(document);

            this.$buoyContainer = $("#buoy-container");
            this.$buoy = this.$buoyContainer.find(".buoy");
            this.$addDream = this.$buoyContainer.find(".buoy.addDream");
            this.$scheduleDream = this.$buoyContainer.find(".buoy.live-chat");
        },
        bindEvents: function () {
            this.liveChat.bindEvents();
            /* Remove Focus */
            this.$document.on("click", this.removeFocusAll.bind(this.$buoy));
            /* Add Focus */
            this.$buoy.on("click", this.addFocus);
            this.$liveChat.on("click",)
        },
        addFocus: function () {
            this.addClass("focus");
        },
        removeFocus: function () {
            this.removeClass("focus");
        },
        /* Live chat */
        liveChat: {
            init: function () {

            },
            cacheDom: function () {
                //This is where I need to access the parent variable "$document" which is initialized in the parents cacheDom method
            },
            bindEvents: function () {

            }
        }
    }
    buoy.init();
}());
```

Comment: There is nothing like a "parent object" in JavaScript. But you can just refer to `buoy.$document`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in `this` to the child, then set it as `this.parent`

```
var buoy = {
  init: function() {
    this.liveChat.init(this);
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  // ...
  liveChat: {
    init: function(parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      //This is where I need to access the parent variable "$document" which is initialized in the parents cacheDom method
      this.parent.$document // do whatever you want here.
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```